# How do you inner join / merge two time series data arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to join/combine two time series arrays into one single array
where there are values for the same time stamp only.

Each time series array looks like this

```
$ARRAY1 = 

        Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1570572000
                [1] => 1570485600
                [2] => 1570399200
                [3] => 1570140000
                [4] => 1570053600
                [5] => 1569967200
                [6] => 1569880800
                [7] => 1569794400
                [8] => 1569535200
                [9] => 1569448800
                [10] => 1569362400
                [11] => 1569276000
                [12] => 1569189600
                [13] => 1568930400
                [14] => 1568844000
                [15] => 1568757600
           )

     [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.7967851
            [1] => -1.5081206
            [2] => -0.4314591
            [3] => 1.3359961
            [4] => 0.8296883
            [5] => -1.7323694
            [6] => -1.1625164
            [7] => 0.4908599
            [8] => -0.5353535
            [9] => -0.2083193
            [10] => 0.5880961
```

and i have a similar one just with another set of data in the column and possibly different timestamps as well.

In MYSQL i would just do an inner join. But in PHP if i had these two arrays `$ARRAY1` and `$ARRAY2` how do i merge them in to an array with
three columns **(column1 = timestamps, column2 = data1, column3 = data2)**
where i only include timestamps where both **data1** and **data2** are present?

`array_merge` or `array_combine` or `array_intersect` are not doing this job.

and i can only think of a crude method through a for loop and doing If **timestamp1 = timestamp2** then update new array with **data1** and **data2**.

but surely there must be a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: did you read the `array_replace_recursive` or `array_merge_recursive` definition?

Comment: @TahaPaksu I looked at it. It doesn’t do the job either.

Comment: I can't think of a way without using a loop then. I misunderstood your question when I wrote my first comment, sorry.

Comment: No worries. I think rationale is that php wasn’t developed to handle time series. Like matplotlib or R does.